# Get folder permissions with only 3 levels of subfolders

Tags: windows, powershell, directory, permissions

First of all: sorry for my bad english.

So, I need to create various reports with all permissions of specified folders.
After some search I found 2 ways.
One is using AccessEnum, that it's almost perfect but it doesn't export all permissions, only the folders that have different permission from the root folder. And I need all of them, even if they are the same of the root folder.

The second one is better, a powershell script, but has one weakness: too much recursive, and one of the folders had an output report of 7GB. Holy shirt.

What I need: to modify the script to go deep only for 3 levels of subfolders, for example:
"C:\Folder1" contains various subfolders but I want the script to go deep only to "C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\"

How can I do it?

This is the script:

```
dir -Recurse "C:\FOLDER" | where { $_.PsIsContainer } | % { $path1 = $_.fullname; Get-Acl $_.Fullname | % { $_.access | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty '.\Application Data' -Value $path1 -passthru }} | Export-Csv "C:\REPORT.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Get-Childitem
```

instead. It has a Depth-Parameter and you can only include Folders.

Reference: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7

Comment: Might want to mention `dir` is an alias of `Get-Childitem`

Comment: Thanks for the info! Then it is very ease for OP to get what he/she needs.

Comment: Use that instead of what? Where? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Itchydon I thinks it's working, I didn't know this parameter. I'm testing it, thanks

Comment: Ok @Itchydon it's working, but I'd like to include the root folder. Do you think it's possible or I need to use `dir -Recurse "C:\" -Depth 3` ?